# Best 2a stepper motor driver for Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, arduino-motor-shield

What is the simplest (from a user/install standpoint) 2a stepper motor driver for an Arduino Uno?

I would like something simple and easy to stack like the [Adafruit Motor/Stepper/Servo Shield for Arduino v2 Kit](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1438)  but unfortunately it only handles 1.2a. I can do basic soldering but I would like to keep things simple and physically stacked or connected if possible. I don't want to use jumpers or a breadboard.

I am trying to run this stepper to simply open and close a door every few hours:
[14:1 Planetary Gearbox High Torque Nema 17 Stepper](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00QA8XUGC)

Using this battery from Amazon:
ExpertPower EXP1250 12V 5Ah

If I'm missing anything please let me know. Your feedback is appreciated.

Comment: While you can do it, this doesn't sound like an application for a stepper motor, but rather some sort of ordinary motor with a mechanical reduction and a limit switch.  If you want to go with this anyway, MOSFET bridges like the TB6612FNG on that Adafruit shield can theoretically be paralleled, but it may also be that setting a reduced current level below the motors rating would be fine for your needs.